# UISearchController's Search Bar shifting down once search is complete

Tags: objective-c, uisearchcontroller

I have added a search bar in the header section of the collection view along with two buttons, in order to accomplish this, I have added a view (onto which I add search bar) and two buttons below it. As shown in figure below.

[image]

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    _headerView= [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [_headerView.searchView addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];
    return _headerView;
```

}

And following are lines I am adding in ViewDidLoad Method

```
  self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = YES;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
```

[image]

Whenever I do search using the search bar, and then dismiss it after the search is done , search bar shifts downwards.

[image]

I am unable to solve this search bar shifting issue from a long time, any clue on how this could be avoided, also after shifting the SearchBar is not responding anymore.

Comment: thats is issue of constrains. i had same issue before , by reseting constrains worked for me.

Comment: How did u do that, i am adding the search bar onto view programatically and not through storyboard. Also note that my search bar gets unresponsive in second search.

Comment: Please dont remove the `objective-c` tag

Comment: leppie - can u answer the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a lay-outing issue. Although it can be solved by moving the search bar view's size back to original size in this method

```
 - searchBarTextDidEndEditing:
```

Example:

In  your .h file,

```
@property (nonatomic) CGRect originalViewSize;
```

In your .m file,

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
self.originalViewSize = self.searchController.searchBar.frame;
}


- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
self.searchController.searchBar.frame = self.originalViewSize ;
}
```

Comment: Well I tired to do it, but I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: It solved my problem , but i added the same piece of code into - (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  method, seems this gets called too, once the search is over.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/4831496/samraan-khaan the searchbar is not responsive once it is done showing the results

Comment: It can only be happening if originalViewSize is not allocated.
Check again, make sure originalViewSize gets the frame size before you assign it to searchBar.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by the following by removing it from the superview and re adding it to the view again.

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    _headerView= [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"RequestHeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self.searchController.searchBar removeFromSuperview];
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    [_headerView.searchView addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];
    return _headerView;
}
```